# How do I create settings in android app

Tags: android, settings

in my app I would like to remember some variables such as if the user has logged in once then they will be logged in when they next reopen the app or if they decide to disable some reminders, the app can check if that variable is false and will not show that reminder anymore. Ideally these variables should be global and used by every activity in the app. Where would I store these variables and how do I go about putting it in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) are the way to go.

Comment: I'm just wondering how they work. If I edit the variable in lets say activity 5 and save it as editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode); can I open any of my other activities with boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
and get the value for "silentMode"?